# Base de Datos(My SQL),comandos SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

básicamente a través de que comando, podría calcular el partido que mas votos saco, se que hay que utilizar el Comando Count y MAX, pero al usarlo al mismo tiempo me da error. Les dejo el comando que realice y me da error. Desde ya gracias!!!!!

```
select partidos.nombre,
       max(count(partidos_electores.estado))
  from electores, partidos, partidos_electores
 where (electores.id_elector=partidos_electores.id_elector
   and partidos.codigo_partido=partidos_electores.codigo_partido)
 group by partidos.nombre
```

Cita en bloque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Joaquin. Te invito a repasar [esta información](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/18951) que habla de lo que se necesita en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Puedes usar el enlace `editar` debajo de tu pregunta para agregar los detallse que faltan.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso, ahí lo corregí!!!

Comment: ¿Qué significado tiene el que el valor de `estado` sea `CORRECTO` o `IMPUGNADO`? ¿O no importa, y debes contar a ambos por igual?

Comment: En este caso no importaría que sea correcto o Impugnado, básicamente a través de eso sabemos si el voto fue valido o no, pero en este caso no hace falta saberlo..

Comment: Como eres nuevo, te ánimo a echarle un vistazo al [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Te será útil con las preguntas que hagas en un futuro.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, para lo que buscas, no necesitas la tabla `electores`. Con `partidos` y `partidos_electores` tienes toda la información necesaria.

Puedes hacer un join entre las 2 tablas y agrupar por partidos. Luego, en vez de usar un `MAX`, yo lo hallo más fácil de simplemente ordenar los resultados por la cantidad de registros (votos) y limitar el resultado al primer registro:

```
select p.nombre
  from partidos p
  left join partidos_electores pe
    on pe.codigo_partido = p.codigo_partido
 group by p.codigo_partido, p.nombre
 order by count(pe.codigo_partido) desc
 limit 1
```